# How to generate values for 2 variables to draw a circle

Tags: r, function, graph, simulator

I have been trying to generate random values so that I can construct a circle.
The values of x and y are expected to satisfy the following equation

x^2 + y^2 = 1

Here is the code that I used.

```
par(type = "s")
x <- runif(1000, min = -1, max = 1)
y <- sqrt(1 - x^2)
z <- NULL
z$x <- x
z$y <- y
z <- as.data.frame(z)
plot.new()
plot(z$x, z$y, type = "p")
plot.window(xlim = c(-10,10), ylim = c(-10,10), asp = 1)
```

But the graph I get is not quite what I expected it to be.

1. The graph resembles an upper half of an ellipse rather than a semicircle
2. Why are there no values for y where y < 0

Please find the plot here.[image]

I am also interested in finding out, how to generate random values for x, y, z, a; where x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + a^2 = 10

Comment: `y <- sqrt(1 - x^2)` always gives you positive values of `y`. In any event, the easiest way to get points on the circle is to use `(cos(t), sin(t))` for `t` in the range `[0,2*pi]`

Comment: But it still doesn't explain why the graph looks like an ellipse? I am not able to see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Don't set the plot limits after the plot -- put them in the original `plot` function call

Comment: `plot.new()` starts a plot with the default `asp=` - just use `plot(z$x, z$y, type = "p", asp=1)` once.

Comment: @JohnColeman Could you kindly show me how?

Comment: @AnirudhMurali You're showing a unit circle in a plot with different x and y axis limits. Obviously this will stretch your (half) unit circle to resemble an (half) ellipse.

Comment: `y <- sqrt(1 - x^2) * sample(c(-1,1),1000)`

Comment: You can draw a nice circle with `plot(x = cos(seq(0, 2*pi, length = 100)), y = sin(seq(0, 2*pi, length = 100)), asp = 1, type = 'l')`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you missed @thelatemail's comment:

```
png()
plot(z$x, z$y, type = "p", asp=1)
dev.off()
```

[image]

The reason passing asp=1 to plot.window would fail(if it were called first, and this is what you might have tried) is that `plot` itself calls `plot.window` again, and in the process reacquires the default values. You can see that in the code of plot.default:

```
> plot.default
function (x, y = NULL, type = "p", xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, 
    log = "", main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, 
    ann = par("ann"), axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes, panel.first = NULL, 
    panel.last = NULL, asp = NA, ...) 
{
    localAxis <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) Axis(...)
    localBox <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) box(...)
    localWindow <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) plot.window(...)
#.... omitted the rest of the R code.
```

(Calling `plot.window` after that `plot` call should not be expected to have any favorable effect.)

Comment: Thank you, this clarified things for me with plot()

Answer (score 3):

The problem is within this part of your code:

```
x <- runif(1000, min = -1, max = 1)
y <- sqrt(1 - x^2)enter code here
```

This problem arises from interpreting two distinct mathematical entities as the same (functions and equations are two different things). A function f takes an input x, and returns a **single** output f(x). Equations don't have this limitation, so if you are encoding this equation as a function, <del>you will lose half the points in the circle</del>, you will generate all the points in the upper semicircle.

Since the circle equation has **two** y outputs for any x value you can just generate two pairs of coordinates for each point generated by your uniform distribution like this:

```
x1 = runif(1000, min = -1, max = 1)
x2 = x1
y1 = sqrt(1 - x1^2)
y2 = (-1)*y1
x = c(x1,x2)
y = c(y1,y2)
plot(x,y, asp=1)
```

[image: It should generate something close to this]

As John Coleman recommended in his comment, i'd prefer using parametric/polar coordinates instead. Generate angles in radians between 0 and 2pi and then calculate the appropriate x and y positions using the generated angle and the radius you want.

```
radius = 1
theta = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 2*pi)
x = radius * cos(theta)
y = radius * sin(theta)
plot(x,y, asp=1)
```

For the last part of your question, for each value of a variable, you'd have to work out all the possible tuples that solve the equation, and if `z` and `a`  are also variables, it may not be possible to represent it solely on a 2-dimensional graph.